# Why do multiple decimals in a JavaScript list throw a 'missing ] after element list' error?

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons that I use to diff some revisions in CVS:

Button A:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:var from = get_diff_from(this.form,2); var to = get_diff_to(this.form,2); parent.show_file('196382', 'telecom.mod', 'teleTWTA.c', from, to, 'webtools/cvsweb/cvsweb.cgi', 'fsw', 
get_chg_array([1.2,1.3], [0,196382], from, to));" value="Diff teleTWTA.c">
```

Button B:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:var from = get_diff_from(this.form,3); var to = get_diff_to(this.form,3); parent.show_file('196383', 'telecom.mod/test/solaris.ut/telecom_twta.exe', 'ut_teleTWTA.c', from, to, 'webtools/cvsweb/cvsweb.cgi', 
'fsw', get_chg_array([1.1.1.1,1.2], [0,196383], from, to));" value="Diff ut_teleTWTA.c">
```

Button A works fine, but button B chokes on clicking, and throws:

> 'missing ] after element list'.

The only explanation I can come up with is the longer CVS revision number (1.1.1.1) in button B. Why would JS break on this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: You don't need the "javascript:" prefix for code in "onfoo" attribute values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value `1.1.1.1` should be enclosed in quotes, as it is a string, not a valid number.  Otherwise, it will try to be evaluated as an object with nested properties named `1`.

**EDIT:** Actually, since `1` is not a valid javascript variable name, I'm not exactly sure how the runtime will attempt to evaluate `1.1.1.1`.  In any case, it's certainly not valid.

Comment: ah, I see! so the others work as a floating point decimal, but once you get past 1 decimal, it's gotta be a string or else JS starts treating it as an object.

Comment: It's indeed not a valid number, but according to the specs it won't do a property lookup, since variable names cannot be numbers.

Comment: @pimvdb - Thanks for the clarification. After I posted I did some research and found this out myself. Edited my post.